# Vampire Mind Eye's Theatre to Vampire the Masquerade

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, conversion, vampire-the-requiem, minds-eye-theatre

I was wondering about if there's some "translation" guide to use the characters from one system to the other, as the Vampire the Requiem to Vampire The Masquerade.

It's just because there's a Ventrue Merit, called "Aura of Control" ("Aura de Mando" in Spanish) and I've not found it in any of the Masquerade books (even in the Lore of the Clans).

Are there some rules? Can they be applied as they are described?

Answer (score 5):

### **There isn't.**

By Night Studios creates the LARP rules under a separate license from White Wolf than Onyx Path has, so there's no easy way to produce a crossover product without finagling. Moreover, that Merit is scaled for a live-action chronicle where NPCs are few and far between. In a tabletop game, it'd be massively overpowered.

Answer (score -2):

> Are there some rules?

Yes, there is one! A vital part of any WoD game is the *Rule 0*, which allows your Storyteller to shape the rules as they want. If you have a suggestion, go ahead and tell your Storyteller what do you want and why do you want it. If you have good reasons and your ST will believe that the game will become better, it will be accepted. However, even if there would be such a rule, your Storyteller could forbid using it.

Same goes for WoD LARP: you can suggest things and get your suggestions accepted (or declined).